# template-id does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm not sure why specialization of the `size` function template for `TCollection` fails.

```
template <typename C>
using detect_size = decltype(std::declval<C>().size());

template <typename C>
constexpr auto size(const C& c) -> decltype(c.size()) { return c.size(); }

template <typename C>
inline std::enable_if_t<
  !is_detected<detect_size,C>::value, size_t >
size(const C& c) { return std::distance( std::begin(c), std::end(c) ); }

template <class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(const T (&array)[N]) noexcept { return N; }

template <>
auto size<TCollection>(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

GCC gives me

```
error: template-id 'size<TCollection>' for 'auto size(const TCollection&)'
does not match any template declaration
```

`is_detected` is implemented as [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

EDIT:

- Specifying return type explicitly doesn't change anything;
- If I use overloading, the implementation using `std::distance` gets picked up.

Overload code:

```
auto size(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

Comment: You need to specify return type instead of relying on automatic return type deduction. Also template parameter for `detect_size` is missing.

Comment: You might use overload instead.

Comment: @VTT Where is the parameter for `detect_size` missing?

Comment: `detect_size` is only used once... and that one time it is used without template parameter

Comment: @VTT That's correct. `is_detected` takes a template as the first argument, and then gives it arguments. Look at the link in the question. There's no mistake there.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to `<experimental/type_traits>` right now. However if `is_detected` accepts template as the first argument then `detect_size` is not a valid parameter. Because `detect_size` is an alias template.

Comment: That's how SFINAE works. You can try my implementation: https://github.com/ivankp/ivanplib/blob/master/ivanp/detect.hh

Comment: Also, if you look at the cppreference link, the examples there use alias templates.

Comment: @VTT: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com has `<experimental/type_traits>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the exact same declaration of your generic template for your specialization, so:

```
template <>
std::enable_if_t<!is_detected<detect_size, TCollection>::value, size_t >
size<TCollection>(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

Simpler is to use overload:

```
auto size(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44598b896a5e9600)

Answer (score 0):

Jarod42's answer is only partially applicable to my situation.

There are two things I didn't realize:

1. Function template specialization must return the same type as the base case.

The exact way the return type is spelled out is not important. So, instead of the definition suggested by Jarod42

```
template <>
std::enable_if_t<!is_detected<detect_size, TCollection>::value, size_t >
size<TCollection>(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

it suffices to write

```
template <>
size_t size(const TCollection& c) { return c.GetSize(); }
```

2. The overload won't work if it's definition appears after the function call.

If the code is structured like this:

```
template <typename T>
size_t size(const T& x) { return x.size(); }

template <typename T>
std::vector<int> reserve_same_number_of_ints(const T& x) {
  std::vector<int> vec;
  vec.reserve(size(x));
  return vec;
}

/* specialize or overload here for special_type */

/* call reserve_same_number_of_ints on the special_type */
```

A template specialization is picked up, but an overload is not.